# Increase height of TextView from bottom to top when text goes to new line

Tags: android, textview, android-wrap-content

Basically, the height of **TextView** increases to the bottom whenever the text goes to a new line. But I want **TextView** height increase to the top.

Normally this is what happens when text size increases and goes to the new line

[image: Normally this is what happen when text size increases and goes to the new line]

And this is what I need when text size increases and goes to the new line

[image]

**Note: Height of Textview is set to WRAP_CONTENT**

Layout

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<androidx.emoji.widget.EmojiTextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_message"
    style="@style/TvChatMessage.Sent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Style :

```
<style name="TvChatMessage.Sent">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/work_sans_regular</item>
    <item name="android:lineSpacingExtra">@dimen/dimen_3dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingStart">@dimen/dimen_10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingEnd">@dimen/dimen_10dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/txt_body_large</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/dimen_3dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Add your layout file which you currently have

Comment: @ADM please review edited question

Comment: Seems like your Edit text is at the top because of `layout_constraintTop_toTopOf` .. So this is the expected behavior..

Comment: I am not sure but I think you are getting me wrong, My Issue is with the height of Textview. Please tally both images to get more information about the issue.